Should I use one-way or two-way anova?
There are eight groups of treatment with different concentrations and different. Initially, we thought about using two-way ANOVA with the factors being 1. the type of experimental setup and 2. the different concentrations.  However, the types of concentration are only applicable to the experimental setups and leave no room for the control and other groups to be compared.
Experimental Treatment:
Treatment A: Concentration (50g, 100g, 150g)
Treatment B: Concentration (50g, 100g, 150g)
What should I really use?

I don't think it's possible to give a good answer to this question without some clarification. You say that there are 8 treatment groups, but then you only list 6. We also don't know what your research questions are, or if any kind of ANOVA is even appropriate for the data.

i am so sorry abt the confusion, there a total 6 experimental groups, and with two control groups, positive and negative, 8 in total
